# change database connection of codeigniter migration

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to change database connection of codeigniter migration.

My default database is DB1, But I want to change connection to DB2.

How can I do that? default coding as the following .

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Add_blog extends CI_Migration {

public function up()
{
    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
        'blog_id' => array(
            'type' => 'INT',
            'constraint' => 5,
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
            'auto_increment' => TRUE
        ),
        'blog_title' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100',
        ),
        'blog_description' => array(
            'type' => 'TEXT',
            'null' => TRUE,
        ),
    ));

    $this->dbforge->create_table('blog');
}

public function down()
{
    $this->dbforge->drop_table('blog');
}
```

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The dbforge library uses the same connection that CI's other database parts. Since there's only one connection, you would have to change the database of that connection. If you are on MYSQL, you can surround your code with two [`use database` calls](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html):

```
// switch to the second db
$this->db->query('use DB2');

// put DB2 stuff here

// switch back    
$this->db->query('use DB');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->load->database();
```

for change the DB-Connection. In config/database.php you can define multiple DB-Connections. For example, to change to the system-DB use this command:

```
$this->load->database('system');
```

I use it for migrations and place the command in my Migrate-Controller´s constructor.

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('system'); //Use the system-Connection for DB-Manipulation
        $this->load->library('migration');
    }

    /**
     * Migrate to latest or current version
     * @return void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        ...
```