# Where should I Initializing the Forge Class in CodeIgniter and use the create_database function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-migration

I am reading [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html#init) documentation regarding the **Forge Class** of **CodeIgniter** and I like the idea that I can create a new DB using this class, that is great just what I need. 
What I need is to use this **create_database**

```
$this->dbforge->create_database('db_name')
```

But I was wondering where should the code of the **Forge Class** should go exactly? Should it be in one of the controllers does it have a better place? Where is the best practice for doing this? should it be in a library or in the migration folder if so in what function? the **up** function? CodeIgniter doesn't specify in the documentation!

this is what I have so far added the code to create a table but where does the **create_database** function goes?:

```
<?php

class Migration_Users extends CI_Migration {
    public function up(){
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`role_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`username` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`password` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`ban_reason` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`newpass` varchar(34) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`newpass_key` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`newpass_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`last_ip` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`last_login` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        $this->dbforge->add_field("`deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'");

        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);

        $this->dbforge->create_table('users', TRUE);
    }

    public function down(){
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your need out there in net try to google it :)

You need to create a file inside this new directory and the naming format has to start with your version number followed by the name of your class (make it is descriptive of the changes that you are making i.e. your first one might be: initial_schema). My first migration file was called: 001_initial_schema.php and my next one could be 002_add_comments.
Your file would look something like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Initial_schema extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'postid' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ),
            'content' => array(
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => TRUE,
            ),
        ));

        $this->dbforge->create_table('posts');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('posts');
    }
}
```

You’ll notice that there are two functions (up and down) in this class. The up function is run when you upgrade to/past this version and likewise the down function is run if you downgrade your database (using the config file) below this version. Your down function will always do the reverse of what your up function does. Essentially restoring your database to the state that it was before that version was added. Also notice that the name of the class above matches the suggested file name I gave earlier (except for the word Migration), the code expects for the class to be named in this way and won’t work without it.

I won’t go into detail about the format to use for the field array when creating or modifying tables as CodeIgniter’s user guide on the Database Forge Class already explains this perfectly.

The only caveat I noticed is when you want to have a text or varchar field with a null default value. Normally in phpMyAdmin you would expect to tick the Null field and also set the default value to Null.  However all you need to do here is specify null as TRUE which you should be able to see from my example above. If you try to define default as null then it will actually set the default as a blank string. I assume that this issue will get cleared up eventually but as long as you keep it in mind then it’s not hard to avoid.

Putting into Pra

- See more at: http://robertsettle.com/2012/07/codeigniter-migrations/#sthash.8NOezY86.dpuf

Comment: Where does the **create_database** function goes? This is what I want to know

Comment: "You need to create a file inside this new directory" Read above link

Comment: create a directory in the application directory called migrations.

Comment: the link doesn't say anything about the $this->dbforge->create_database('db_name') function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500733/codeigniter-dbforge-create-database-and-tables I think $this->dbforge->create_database('db_name') can be done after load load->library('migration'); and config $config['migration_enabled'] = TRUE;