# creating a database with username and password credentials codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter-3

So i am new to codeigniter, what i want to accomplish is to create a new database using the dbforge class by providing the parameters such as the name of the database, password and the username of this new created database.
so far i have been able to create the database, but i want the username and password to be specified for this database too. How do i accomplish this.

so far i have this function

```
 public function dbcreate($db, $user, $pwd)
{
    $this->dbforge->create_database($db);
}
```

how do i go about incorporating the $user and $password within the newly created database.

Comment: this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500733/codeigniter-dbforge-create-database-and-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $fields = array(
                        'id' => array(
                                                 'type' => 'INT',
                                                 'unsigned' => TRUE,
                                                 'auto_increment' => TRUE
                                          ),
                        'username' => array(
                                                 'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                                                 'constraint' => '100',
                                          ),
                        'password' => array(
                                                 'type' =>'VARCHAR',
                                                 'constraint' => '100',

                                          ),

                );

    $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('users', TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks @CristianR for your answer. the code you have provided is for creating a table. But what i want is to create the database with its username and password. for example when you want to create a database with php, normally you would provide the name of the database you wan to create, its passsword along with the username. now i want to accomplish that with codeigniter. thanks.